# KafkaStreams (new) processor API + split

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm having some troubles using `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.Processor<K1,V1,K2,V2>`. What I have to do is

1. Join with custom logic (some record may go under multiple keys) and
2. Emit error on a DLQ if join does not happen after a period of time (done via a punctuator).

I use a custom type `Try<V, E extends Error>` to wrap either a success or a failure. So I do my stuff and in the end forward with my processorContext<K, Try<V,E>> both inside my punctuator callback and my process method. Now the trouble is that I have to split the tries containing errors from the try containing result. And here I get lost. I should connect my processor via processorApi to a split node, but I can't get an instance of it via the stream API which is not already connected to a stream. (I would like to call someting like `inputStream.process(myJoinProcessorSupplier).split` but I can't as process returns void).

What is the best way to do this?

I thought about resorting to a ValueTransformerWithKey (but it looks like an older API and still have to figure out the details of how an implementation with this interface should work) or serializing my Try object and then read again in order to have it in a KStream and perform a regular split (seems very inefficient).